# Increment 10 for each node exists in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Starting with 10 and Need to increment 10 for each node of the order item is exists
Can please anyone help me to achieve this output. need XSLT 2.0 code for  this output
Starting with 10 and Need to increment 10 for each node of the order item is exists
Can please anyone help me to achieve this output. need XSLT 2.0 code for  this output
Starting with 10 and Need to increment 10 for each node of the order item is exists
Can please anyone help me to achieve this output. need XSLT 2.0 code for  this output
Starting with 10 and Need to increment 10 for each node of the order item is exists
Can please anyone help me to achieve this output. need XSLT 2.0 code for  this output
Input:

```
<orderHeader>
            <distributionChannelCode>ABC</distributionChannelCode>
            <orderItem>
  
            </orderItem>
              <orderItem>
               
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
               
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                
            </orderItem>
             <orderItem>
                
            </orderItem>
        </orderHeader>
```

OutPut:

```
<orderHeader>
            <distributionChannelCode>ABC</distributionChannelCode>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>10</productCode>
            </orderItem>
              <orderItem>
                <productCode>20</productCode>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>30</productCode>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>40</productCode>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>50</productCode>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>60</productCode>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>70</productCode>
            </orderItem>
            <orderItem>
                <productCode>80</productCode>
            </orderItem>
             <orderItem>
                <productCode>90</productCode>
            </orderItem>
        </orderHeader>
```

Comment: This is a trivial task: simply multiply the position by 10.

Comment: You're not ready to ask a question here.  Read [**Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)  Then read [ask].  Then write some code.  Then come back with a [mcve] and a specific question regarding where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="orderItem">
  <xsl:copy>
    <productCode><xsl:value-of select="position()*10"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```